# How to view <swagger-ui-url>/app.yaml content in the browser and not download the yaml file instead?

Tags: yaml, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using swagger api documentation tool for my backend, and I need to view the contents of the .yaml file in the browser when the url is called. But instead, I always end up having the file downloaded.

This is the content of my SwaggerUI  tag:

```
<script>
  window.onload = function() {

  // Build a system
  const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    url: "./app.yaml",
    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
    deepLinking: true,
    presets: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
      SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
    ],
    plugins: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
    ],
    layout: "StandaloneLayout"
  })

  window.ui = ui
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Not a duplicate @Helen. I think this is because of updating Swagger to the latest version. For my application still using the previous version, I can view the content of yaml. So it has nothing to do with the browser I believe. But thanks anyway. :)

Comment: By "view the content of yaml" do you mean render YAML in Swagger UI or view the actual YAML file?

Comment: @Helen I meant to render the content.

Comment: Your code looks correct. Are there any errors in the browser console? Do you use the latest version of Swagger UI? How are you running Swagger UI (e.g. by opening index.html in a browser from, using Docker, embedded in your app, generated by a 3rd-party framework, etc.)?

Comment: There are no errors in the browser. On firing the url - "www.myapp.com/myapp/app.yaml", it automatically starts downloading the yaml file. I'm using latest Swagger UI on Nginx API Gateway.

Comment: Can you `curl -I www.myapp.com/myapp/app.yaml` and add the headers to your post?

Comment: I have a similar case, I get "Failed to load API definition. Fetch error Not Found ./app.yaml" (As a popup dialog inside Swagger-UI page)